# Monit: search for text at a url with https protocol

Tags: monit

For some reason, monit configuration for monitoring the presence of text at a URL has been failing constantly in the last 48 hours. Here is the relevant config data:

```
if failed (url https://www.Example.com.com/where-to-buy/ and content == 'Online Retail Partners' and timeout 40 seconds)

     then alert

if failed (url https://www.Example.com.com/products/high-absorption and content == 'You May Also Like' and timeout 20 seconds)

     then alert

if failed (url https://www.Example.com.com/health-interests/bone-health and content == 'Refine' and timeout 20 seconds)

     then alert

if failed (url https://www.Example.com.com/search?keywords=vitamin+d and content == 'Vegan D3' and timeout 20 seconds)

        then alert
```

This all worked great for months/years.

We are getting inundated with monit alerts as follows:

```
Date:        21 Feb 12:11:32 -0600
Host:        Example.com.
Service:     httpd
Action:      Alert
Description: connection succeeded to [www.Example.com]:443/health-interests/bone-health [TCP/IP TLS]

Date:        21 Feb 12:11:33 -0600
Host:        Example.com
Service:     httpd
Action:      Alert
Description: failed protocol test [HTTP] at [www.Example.com]:443/products/high-absorption [TCP/IP TLS] -- Cannot resolve [www.Example.com]:443


Your faithful employee,
M/Monit
Date:        21 Feb 12:14:00 -0600
Host:        Example.com
Service:     httpd
Action:      Alert
Description: connection succeeded to [www.Example.com]:443/products/high-absorption [TCP/IP TLS]
```

I'm not sur why we are failing the protocol tests.

Is there a different way to set port 443, https protocol while searching for text in a URL?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot resolve [www.Example.com]

Monit is not able to resolve the IP of the remote service. Please investigate name resolution at the host level (DNS etc...)